# Rails 5 - how to write a view helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, view-helpers

I am trying to learn how to use helpers in my Rails 5 app.

I have an org_requests model, which has attributes to hold the date on which various steps are taken. I'm trying to use the controller to update those attributes when the relevant controller action is saved.

For example, I have an attribute called :approved_at. In my controller I have an action called approved with:

```
def approved
    @org_request = current_user.organisation.org_requests.find(params[:id])

    if @org_request.state_machine.transition_to!(:approved)
      @org_request.update_attribute(approved_at: Time.zone.now)
      flash[:notice] = "You've added this member."
      redirect_to org_requests_path
    else
      flash[:error] = "You're not able to manage this organisation's members"
      redirect_to :index
    end
  end
```

I think this line:

```
 @org_request.update_attribute(approved_at: Time.zone.now)
```

should save the time now, when the approved action is saved.

In my view, I'm trying to render the time at which the relevant actions were taken. To do that, I'm trying to write:

```
<% @org_requests.each do |org_req| %>
<%= text_for_time_of_status_change(org_req.current_state) %>
```

I then have a helper that has:

```
def text_for_time_of_status_change(current_state)
        case current_state
          when 'requested'
            org_request.requested_at.try(:strftime, ' %l:%M  %e %B %Y')
          when 'approved'
            org_request.approved_at.try(:strftime, ' %l:%M  %e %B %Y')
          when 'rejected'
                org_request.rejected_at.try(:strftime, ' %l:%M  %e %B %Y')
          when 'removed'
            org_request.removed_at.try(:strftime, ' %l:%M  %e %B %Y')
        end
    end
```

I'm not able to give my helper an org_request like so (because it won't accept the '.'):

```
def text_for_time_of_status_change(org_request.current_state)
```

This isn't right. I'm not even sure whether I need to be using '@' in front of org_request (although I get an error when I try that).

Can anyone see what I need to do in order to use a view helper?

These articles: http://6ftdan.com/allyourdev/2015/01/28/rails-helper-methods/ seem to suggest that the helpers aren't meant to be used for presentation logic. Maybe they're meant for some other types of actions. I'm not sure I'm even trying to use the helper for the proper purpose.

Comment: what is the error that you get?

Comment: what do you meen "I'm not able to give my helper an org_request like so (because it won't accept the '.')" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to update `text_for_time_of_status_change` method and pass `org_req` instead of `org_req.current_state`. You are getting error because you want to access `org_request` variable but didn't pass it to the helper method. After this change don't forget to update helper method code so you call `org_request.current_state` instead of `current_state` in `case`

Answer (score 0):

you have to fix your `helper` and would be better to use partial in your case:

helper:

```
def text_for_time_of_status_change(org_request)
  case org_request.current_state
  when 'requested'
    org_request.requested_at.try(:strftime, ' %l:%M  %e %B %Y')
  when 'approved'
    org_request.approved_at.try(:strftime, ' %l:%M  %e %B %Y')
  when 'rejected'
    org_request.rejected_at.try(:strftime, ' %l:%M  %e %B %Y')
  when 'removed'
    org_request.removed_at.try(:strftime, ' %l:%M  %e %B %Y')
  end
end
```

than create partial:

_requested.html.erb

```
<%= text_for_time_of_status_change(org_request) %>
```

than in view use collection in partial:

```
<%= render partial: 'requested', collection: @org_requests, as: org_request %>
```

Comment: Thanks very much. Why is it better to use a collection partial?

Comment: Partial seems more sexy,  and in this case you avoid logic in view (rails way)